# how to get proper substring of html() result; unexpected effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Observe the below phenomenon:

```
<div id="testdiv"><p>test text test one two three</p></div>
```

```js
var i = 1;
var left_over;
while (i < 4) {
    i++;
    var last_index = $("#testdiv").html().lastIndexOf(' ');
    left_over = $("#testdiv").html().substring(last_index).concat(left_over);
    $("#testdiv").html( $("#testdiv").html().substring(0, last_index) );
}
console.log($("#testdiv").html()); // <p>test text test</p>
console.log(left_over); // one</p> two</p> three</p>undefined
```

Every time you substring the result of `.html()`, you don't actually remove the html tags. Probably useful in most circumstances.

Observe the consequences on left_over. I have very little ability to finding out where the p tag initially ended. In my case even more of a problem when using i and b tags. Also a mysterious but less problematic appearance of undefined.

Is there a good way of getting the tags not to duplicate, without turning the result of `html()` into a proper string? I require getting the string from the div in the real code, because my while loop removes words one at a time from the div until the div is less than a particular height.

Comment: A suggestion: maybe your content doesn't allow it, but if you're only targeting actual content, instead of html, you could work with text of child. So you're not messing the tags. Like this $("#testdiv").children('p').text().

Comment: Sounds like a XY problem. Why would you want to do that? `because my while loop removes words one at a time from the div until the div is less than a particular height` This sounds like line clamping: https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/

Comment: Basically it's a pagination problem, but it's too clunky for this particular kind of pagination to split content up by paragraphs alone, which might be half a page long or two lines long.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var i = 1;
  var left_over;
  var text_left_over;
  var text = '' + $("#testdiv").html();
  while (i < 4) {
    i++;
    var last_index = $("#testdiv").html().lastIndexOf(' ');
    text_last_index = text.lastIndexOf(' ');

    left_over = $("#testdiv").html().substring(last_index).concat(left_over);
    text_left_over = text.substring(last_index).concat(text_left_over);

    $("#testdiv").html( $("#testdiv").html().substring(0, last_index) );
    text = text.substring(0, text_last_index);
  }
  console.log($("#testdiv").html());
  console.log(left_over);
  console.log(text); // <p>test text test
  console.log(text_left_over); // one two three</p>undefined
```

I guess I can just double up the code, but it feels super ugly. Maybe it's what I have to do though.